# Ternip can't format a string

Tags: python, xml

[I'm trying to use the library Ternip to add temporay tags to text.](https://github.com/cnorthwood/ternip).

In order to preprocess a document I have to run it through one of the annotators, and I am [currently using the TIMEX3 one.](https://github.com/cnorthwood/ternip/blob/master/ternip/formats/timex3.py)

Now it states that it is supposed to accept an XML document, and I am not entirely sure how to put that in. If I try to put in a string using.

```
TT = Timex3XmlDocument(sampledoc)
```

I got the following error:

```
    221         parser = self.getParser()
    222         try:
--> 223             parser.Parse(string, True)
    224             self._setup_subset(string)
    225         except ParseEscape:

ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Any Idea how I can properly input documents in order for them to be properly annotated?

Comment: maybe your string is not correct XML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source code](https://github.com/cnorthwood/ternip/blob/master/ternip/formats/xml_doc.py) of `XmlDocument` (base class of `Timex3XmlDocument`), the argument should be either *instance of `xml.dom.minidom.Document`* or a *string* representing *well-formed* XML document, so that it can be parsed into `Document` object (relevant portion of the source code included here for easy reference) :

```
class XmlDocument(object):
    def __init__(self, file, nodename=None, has_S=False, has_LEX=False, pos_attr=False):
        if isinstance(file, xml.dom.minidom.Document):
            self._xml_doc = file
        else:
            self._xml_doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(file)
```

So in your particular case, just make sure that `sampledoc` variable references well-formed XML string. For example, the following worked fine for me :

```
from ternip.formats.timex3 import Timex3XmlDocument
>>> raw = '''<root>
... INDEPENDENCE, Mo. _ The North Atlantic Treaty Organizationembraced three of its former rivals, the Czech Republic,Hungary and Poland on <TIMEX3 tid="t3" type="DATE" value="1999-03-12">Friday</TIMEX3>, formally ending the Sovietdomination of those nations that began after World War IIand opening a new path for the military alliance
... </root>'''
... 
>>> doc = Timex3XmlDocument(raw)
>>> print doc
<?xml version="1.0" ?><root>
INDEPENDENCE, Mo. _ The North Atlantic Treaty Organizationembraced three of its former rivals, the Czech Republic,Hungary and Poland on <TIMEX3 tid="t3" type="DATE" value="1999-03-12">Friday</TIMEX3>, formally ending the Sovietdomination of those nations that began after World War IIand opening a new path for the military alliance
</root>
```

Comment: excellent! How could you tell that you needed to make the string into will formed XML?

Comment: Because xml.dom.minidom is an XML parser, meaning it can only naturally handle well-formed XML